# Convert csharp code to VB

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net

I am trying to read an XML into textbox in VB.

Tried all I could but not getting any result

Kindly assist me convert this Csharp code to VB

```
  doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.Load(PATH);
  root = doc.DocumentElement;
  txtName.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Name")[0].InnerText;
  txtAge.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Age")[0].InnerText;
  txtAddress.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Address")[0].InnerText;
```

This was my try

```
doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(PATH)
root = doc.DocumentElement
txtPatientID.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Name").ItemOf(0)
```

but was getting error that "Can not convert to string"

Comment: Where did `InnerText` go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed inner text property at the end

```
txtPatientID.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Name").ItemOf(0).InnerText
```

Full code:

```
doc = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load(PATH)
root = doc.DocumentElement
txtName.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Name")(0).InnerText
txtAge.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Age")(0).InnerText
txtAddress.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Address")(0).InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET have feature that c# doesn't - [XML Child Axis Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx)

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(PATH)
txtName.Text = doc.Root.<Name>.First().Value
txtAge.Text = doc.Root.<Age>.First().Value
txtAddress.Text = doc.Root.<Address>.First().Value
```

Or classic way

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(PATH)
txtName.Text = doc.Root.Element("Name").Value
txtAge.Text = doc.Root.Element("Age").Value
txtAddress.Text = doc.Root.Element("Address").Value
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize variables with the `Dim` keyword:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.load(PATH)
Dim root = doc.DocumentElement
txtPatientID.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Name").ItemOf(0)
```

Comment: if they weren't declared in the C#, they shouldn't be in the VB either. they must have been declared earlier.